# Cannot send file to browser/user

Tags: php, file, header

I'm trying to send a zip file to the user.

```
$file_info = get_file_info($filepath_name);
header("Content-Type: " . get_mime_by_extension($filepath_name));
header("Content-Length: " . $file_info["size"]);
header_remove('Pragma');
header_remove('Cache-Control');
//header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');        
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.urlencode($filepath_name));
header('Location: file://'.$filepath_name);
readfile($filepath_name);
```

`$filepath_name` is set to "D:\dev2.local\storage_users\1\export_data\course_2357.zip".

`readfile()` returns the correct size of file but the file is still not served for downloading.

I've tried all the combinations of headers settings to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found:

This functionality was called via AJAX call, thats why php didnt allow file to be send.

Solution found:
Had to return file path and name back to js from where php was ajaxed and serve file from js.

EDIT:
this is the workaround I used:

```
                                var hostname = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');

                            jQuery('<iframe>', {
                               src: hostname + value.return_zip,
                               id:  'iFrame_zip_download',
                               frameborder: 0,
                               scrolling: 'no'
                           }).appendTo('#export_import_status');
```

Where value.return_zip is relative path to file on server (/storage_users/xx/xx/xx.zip). I then add hostname and it turns out nicely for example: https://www.google.com/storage_users/xx/xx/xx.zip.
iFrame is hidden in status div.

Answer (score 3):

`header('Location: file://'.$filepath_name);` looks problematic. This is a special use of the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function which sends a 302 Redirect HTTP status to the browser, redirecting to the URL specified.

It's not adding anything here, I'd remove it.

The correct MIME type for ZIP archives is `application/zip` not `application/octet-stream`. Sending the correct header makes it more likely the browser will open the file in the correct program.

URL-encoding the full path to the file results in a filename that's 69 characters long. I think it's unlikely this is long enough to be causing a problem, but we might as well simplify it by just sending the basename "course_2357.zip". I don't think URL-encoding the filename is necessary at all - this seems to stem from an Internet Explorer 8 hack to get UTF-8 characters working which isn't required in your case - but I've left it in place as it isn't doing any harm.

I've used PHP's built-in `filesize` rather than `get_file_info` because I don't have CodeIgniter installed. I assume this is where this function comes from?

The following code based on what you've provided above works for me:

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath_name));
header_remove('Pragma');
header_remove('Cache-Control');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.urlencode(basename($filepath_name)));
readfile($filepath_name);
```

Comment: Doesnt change result :(

Comment: I've added some more suggestions which might be helpful.

Comment: Good nice explanation, but still nothing happens. This is my return header: Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=course_2357.zip
Content-Length:9235
Content-Type:application/zip
Date:Thu, 24 Mar 2016 12:01:47 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=94
P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT
Server:Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) mod_auth_token/1.0.6 PHP/5.6.10
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.10

Comment: One update: file is now served into response (chrome inspector..). Does that help you?

Comment: Those headers all look good. If the file is served, what is the problem exactly? When you say "nothing happens" what exactly do you mean? I've tested the code snippet above in Chrome on Linux and Windows and it works fine, so the problem must be outside the scope of the code you've provided. Chrome downloads the file without prompting, and it appears in the download bar at the bottom of the window. If this isn't happening for you, are you outputting anything after the `readfile` function has returned? What happens if you add `exit;` immediately after `readfile($filepath_name);`?

Comment: Well, the save file as form doesnt show, contents of zip file is just written into response, which I see in network.. exit doesnt help either. I guess I have some other code messing with this functionality.. Thank you for you help!

Comment: I'm at a loss, I'm afraid, why Chrome would be receiving the correct headers and outputting the file inline. Sorry. The only remaining thing that's a bit suspicious is that `Expires` header set way in the past. Can you get rid of that with `header_remove`? I doubt it will fix the problem, just clutching at straws now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's some problem with your header.

You could try something like this:

```
ob_start();
//OR
ob_clean();
header("Content-Type: " . get_mime_by_extension($filepath_name));
/* Other code */
```

Comment: None of the combinations work :( I also added ob_end_flush() to the end of that code, still no-go..

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if that is the order you are typing, but: have you tried putting:

```
$filepath_name =  "D:\\dev2.local\\storage_users\\1\\export_data\\course_2357.zip"
```

on the top of the code, or at least before the `readfile()`

Waiting for your update.